# Is there any Redis Library for Netty?

Tags: java, redis, netty, nio, reactor-netty

I am writing a Rest Service on Netty Framework which uses Redis to get some data. 
I am looking for a Redis library that can be used with Netty. 
I tried **Jedis** & **Lettuce** and both are impacting the performance(QPS) very badly almost it makes it half. I am executing only 2-3 hget commands per Http Call.

**Lettuce**:

I tried getting the StatefulRedisConnection and tried with both async and sync. Both there was no luck in performance improvements.

There is very little documentation online regarding Redis with Netty.
Need some help in tuning or using Lettuce with Netty or some Netty specific RedisClient/Library.
Any help or useful links are really appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems like the client is the issue but the pattern.
If you are doing 2-3 hget then you need to wait for 3 response, but you can improve it.

1. If the hgets are not related you can call these three in a pipeline, see: Jedis [AdvancedUsage](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#pipelining)
2. If these hgets are related you might want to packed them in LUA script and run it all in one call on Redis, Jedis [Eval](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/latest/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html)

Comment: Result of 1 HGET is dependant on another HGET key. Similarly, there will be more HGET's.

Comment: I would want to wait for these responses to allow other threads to process further like the way netty is implemented.